# Simple HTML help

Tags: html

My `<li>` wont turn into a link for some reason here is my html and css

Hope some one can help.

```
<div class="header_quick_link">
    <ul>
     <li style="padding-left:700px;"><a href="#"><img src="images/signup-off.png" height="26px" alt="sign-up off"/></a></li>
     <li style="padding-left:798px;"><a href="#"><img src="images/login-off.png" height="26px" alt="sign-up off"/></a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>


.header_quick_link{
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: 26px;
position: absolute;
background: url(../images/quicklink.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
z-index: -1;
}

.header_quick_link li {
float: none;
list-style: none;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 6;
height: 26px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "won't turn into a link"? Aren't the `<a>`s clickable? Both href is set to `#`, so it shouldn't really do anything...

Comment: This works fine for me without the css

Answer (score 5):

Alright, you've got a bewildering mix of floats, absolute positioning, lists, background images, foreground images, margins and padding there. Keep it simple. Don't overcomplicate it. Start with some semantic HTML:

```
<div id="signup">
<a href="#"><img src="images/signup-off.png" height="26" alt="sign-up off"/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/login-off.png" height="26" alt="sign-up off"/></a>
</div>
```

then work out how to style it. I imagine you want two links next to each other on the right. Easy done.

```
#signup { overflow: hidden; float: right; }
#signup a { float: left; display: block; margin: 0 10px; padding: 2px 8px; }
```

Comment: I agree with that...it's seems that the second link overlaps the first one.

Comment: @Jochen: It won't overlap because of the `padding-left` set individually on both `<li>`'s

Comment: Just noticed the height attributes were "26px". That's legal CSS but for the height attribute on an img tag, it's just a number (ie "26").